# Why can't make Post Request with Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, http, dart

I want to make a post request but it seems doesn't work... I don't know whats the error but when i click submit button nothing happen i don't know whether the data hasn't been post or not... Is it something wrong with my post method or anything else that may happen been error... Can somebody help me fix this or guide me the right way to make a Post request. Your help will be very appreciates.

PostData.dart

```
class PostData extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostData({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PostDataState createState() => _PostDataState();
}

class Debouncer {
  final int milliseconds;
  VoidCallback action;
  Timer _timer;

  Debouncer({this.milliseconds});

  run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (null != _timer) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds), action);
  }
}

class _PostDataState extends State<PostData> {
  String url = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/HakimRahim46/mockjson/postData";
  insertData() async {
    Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();

    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

    String body =
        jsonEncode({"namalokasi": namalokasi.text, "nama": nama.text});

    await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body).then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.statusCode);
      } else {
        throw Exception("Failed to post data");
      }
    });
  }

  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController namalokasi = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nama = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Create Data Example'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[700],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: TextField(
                maxLines: null,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Nama Lokasi:"),
                controller: namalokasi,
              ),
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.map_rounded),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
                title: TextField(
                  maxLines: null,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Nama Pegawai:",
                  ),
                  controller: nama,
                ),
                leading:
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.person), onPressed: () {})),
            SizedBox(
              height: 32,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                insertData();
                setState(() {
                  print(namalokasi.text);
                  print(nama.text);
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHeader()));
                });
              },
              child: Text("Submit"),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

post request

```
 String url = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/HakimRahim46/mockjson/postData";
      insertData() async {
        Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
    
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    
        String body =
            jsonEncode({"namalokasi": namalokasi.text, "nama": nama.text});
    
        await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body).then((response) {
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            print(response.statusCode);
          } else {
            throw Exception("Failed to post data");
          }
        });
      }
```

Post.dart json

```
class Post {
  Post({
    @required this.kodlokasi,
    @required this.namalokasi,
    @required this.nama,
    @required this.catatan,
    @required this.status,
    @required this.id,
  });

  final String kodlokasi;
  final String namalokasi;
  final String nama;
  final String catatan;
  final String status;
  final String id;

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Post(
        kodlokasi: json["kodlokasi"],
        namalokasi: json["namalokasi"],
        nama: json["nama"],
        catatan: json["catatan"],
        status: json["status"],
        id: json["id"],
      );

  Map toMap() {
    var map = new Map();
    map['kodlokasi'] = kodlokasi;
    map['namalokasi'] = namalokasi;
    map['nama'] = nama;

    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share logs?

Comment: Hey @HakimRahim, I've explained the problem and it's answer in this post. Check it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62656875/flutterphp-i-cannot-post-to-mysql-database-from-my-flutter-app/62657881#62657881

Comment: @HakimRahim, i want to suggest you one more thing. Don't use await and then together in one method. I can see that you're using await http.post().then. There's no need of .then when you're using await. Move the code inside .then to just below of your await http.post() call.

Comment: Alright i tried my best...thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem.
First of all I tried to allow Cors in my backend.
Inspite of that there was still the same issue.
(Because by default flutter web enable web security).

So I follows up this step (I repeat this two times before it works),

**1- Go to flutter\bin\cache and remove a file named: flutter_tools.stamp
2- Go to flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web and open the file chrome.dart.
3- Find '--disable-extensions'
4- Add '--disable-web-security'**

**Don't forget to restart you app then!!!**
(if this don't work on front end, then you have a trouble in your backend)
Good Luck.
Regards.